# How to copy file from remote server over SSH using Paramiko Python? FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, ssh, scp

I am getting the following error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified`

The paths are actually valid, definitely. I do see the files in the folder specified.

[image]

**Update**:
I swapped the local and remote path but still the same error:

[image]

I checked on the remote server again, the file does exist on the server:

[image]

Comment: you mean i should have a `import ssh`?

Comment: sorry, my bad
please note that first parameter to sftp put is localpath and then destination path.

just reverse the arguments.

Comment: I reversed the argument (please see the update in the question) - still the same error!

Comment: `sftp - put` will put the local files on your system to server
`sftp - get` will fetch the remote files to your system

Comment: oh how do i do the opposite then? I am trying to download files from the remote ssh server to my local machine

Comment: http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get

Comment: Your answer helped. Just add it as an answer and I will mark it as an answer. Thank you very much. I had the confusion between get and put for sftp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch remote files to local system you should be using SFTP - GET rather than PUT(which does vice versa)

Paramiko documentation on GET
http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.get